# By running git log I get not found, git latest version

Tags: git

i am experiencing a problem with git latest version.
When I git log I get the following result ..
=: 1: =: =: not found

I've already tried to install git again but nothing changes

Comment: Please provide log when you execute `git log` and what git prints

Comment: Hi simone, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to better answer your query, could you please update the question with whatever output you received on running `git log`

Comment: Also some information about your platform (Windows, Linux, whatever) might be useful, along with _how_ you installed git.

Comment: Hi the operating system is linux ubuntu 16.04 version of git 2.23.0
and if I do `git log` I get
`. =: 1: =: =: not found`
Git was installed with apt-install git-all